# EF Include child's several collections of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have strange error in Entity Framework. I have next models:

```
public class ModelLetterIncoming : ModelBase
{
    public ModelLetterIncoming()
    {
        attachedFiles = new List<ModelLetterIncomingAttachedFile>();
        contactPersons = new List<ModelContactPerson>();
    }

    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateAdd { get; set; }

    public string LetterText { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelContactPerson> contactPersons { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelLetterIncomingAttachedFile> attachedFiles { get; set; }
}

public class ModelContactPerson : ModelBase
{
    public ModelContactPerson()
    {
        this.companies = new List<ModelCompany>();
        this.phones = new List<ModelContactPersonPhones>();
        this.emails = new List<ModelContactPersonEmails>();
    }

    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelCompany> companies { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelContactPersonPhones> phones { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelContactPersonEmails> emails { get; set; }

    public int positionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelContactPersonsPositions position { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

public class ModelContactPersonPhones : ModelBase
{
    public int contactPersonId { get; set; }

    public string phone { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelContactPerson contactPerson { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.phone;
    }
}

public class ModelContactPersonEmails : ModelBase
{
    public int contactPersonId { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelContactPerson contactPerson { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.email;
    }
}

public class ModelCompany : ModelBase
{
    public ModelCompany()
    {
        this.contactPersons = new List<ModelContactPerson>();
    }

    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EDRPOU { get; set; }

    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public int? cityId { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelCity city { get; set; }

    public int typeOfOwnershipId { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelTypeOfOwnership typeOfOwnership { get; set; }

    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }

    public string ApartmentNumber { get; set; }

    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this.city + " " + this.StreetName + " " + this.HouseNumber + " " + this.ApartmentNumber;
        }
    }

    public int subscriberStatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual ModelSubscriberStatus subscriberStatus { get; set; }

    public string SubscriberCode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelContactPerson> contactPersons { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

I've disabled Lazy Loading in my DbContext class because I'm creating a new DbContext instance for every query:

```
public MysqlDbContext(string conenctionString) : base(conenctionString)
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = conenctionString;
}
```

I'm using ths method to get my letters:

```
public static IQueryable<ModelLetterIncoming> GetLettersIncoming(IQueryable<ModelLetterIncoming> query)
    {
        IQueryable<ModelLetterIncoming> result = from letterIncoming in query.
            Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.attachedFiles).
            Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons).
            Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons.Select(contactPerson => contactPerson.phones)).
            //Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons.Select(contactPerson => contactPerson.emails)).
            Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons.Select(contactPerson => contactPerson.position))
            //Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons.Select(contactPerson => contactPerson.companies.Select(company => company.city).Select(city => city.district).Select(district => district.region)))
            select letterIncoming;

        try
        {
            var tmp = result.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The problem is when I uncomment this line,

```
//Include(letterIncoming => letterIncoming.contactPersons.Select(contactPerson => contactPerson.emails)).
```

I cannot call ToList() and get results on IQueryable. I have NullReferenceException:
[image]

It looks like I cannot Include more than one collection for some reason.

Comment: I cannot use letterIncoming.contactPersons.emails because of letterIncoming.contactPersons is a Collection, only instance of contactPersons  have emails property

Comment: That's definitely strange. What EF version is this?

Comment: @IvanStoev, I'm using EntityFramework 6.0.0.0. Now when I've updated some library (don't remember what exactly, I think, it was EntityFramework.dll v6.2.0), I've gor error "method or operation is not implemented"

Comment: Could be a bug. Did you try (for the sake of test) using the `string` overloads of `Include`, e.g. `Include("attachedFiles").Include("contactPersons.phones").Include("contactPersons.emails").Include("contactPersons.position")`?

Comment: @IvanStoev, Include("contactPersons").Include("contactPersons.phones") is working, but Include("contactPersons").Include("contactPersons.phones") .Include("contactPersons.emails") is not - in such case I'm getting NullReferenceException

Comment: In other words, it's the same issue as with your original code. How about commenting the include for `phones` and uncommenting the include for `emails` to see if there is some problem with `emails` property in general. If that works, then we'll be sure the issue is with multiple collection properties and probably there is nothing we can do because it would be definitely EF bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I've tried different combinations - emails and phones, phones and companies, emails and companies - any of that not working. only separately emails or phones or companies

Comment: Is `ModelBase` mapped to a table too? In other words, are the entities mapped in an inheritance scheme that is reflected in the database structure (like TPH, TPT, TPC)? Or is each subclass mapped independently? The latter looks more likely, but it's important to get a picture of all the moving parts here.

Comment: @GertArnold, no, the ModelBase is just a base abstract class that have an abstract Id property whick is overriding in inherited classes or ignoring in OnModelCreating if not overriding

Comment: So it's a pretty straightforward model. Could you please edit your question to display a minimal case that reproduces the problem? Note that for others to look at it you must be 100% certain of the EF version you're in as well as the targeted .Net framework version.

Comment: @GertArnold, my EntityFramework version is 6, and my app is using .NET Framework 4.0, EF 6 supports .NET Framework 4.0. My question describes this problem fully.